# Build gulp subproject

Tags: javascript, gulp, build-process

I'm very new to javascript and gulp, and I need to use external library fetched from GitHub that uses gulp to build specific version.

What's the way to build it from gulp, assuming that library lies at `.\chart.js\` and command shell build command looks like `gulp build --types=Line`?

Project structure:

```
main_project\
  | chart.js\ - fetched from github
  | | gulpfile.js - gulp builds library using this file
  | | *other files from library*
  | *main project files and folders*
  | gulpfile.js - I want to build library from here while building my project
```

Answer (score 0):

Go inside that folder and insure that it has **Gulpfile.js** or **gulpfile.js**

Now inside your terminal try to cd into that folder

```
> cd path_to_that_folder
> gulp
```

the gulp command by default will attempt to run the `default` task,
so make sure the gulp file has one.

Here is :[gulp documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp)

Comment: I know how to build it from shell, but I want to build in `gulpfile.js` from parrent project.

Comment: The ``gulpfile.js`` is inside a parent folder ?

Comment: Parrent project has it's own `gulpfile.js` and I want to build fetched from github library that has it's own `gulpfile.js`. is there a proper way to do it without directly calling shell commands from parrent project's gulp task to run another instance of gulp?

Comment: Sorry @Pavlus can you explain it more, because i'm not understanding what you want exactly ?

Comment: Found simmilar answered question. Closed as duplicate.